# Track mouse coordinates

Tags: javascript, html, event-handling

> **Problem Statement**
>   Write a JavaScript program that prints the mouse coordinates in a text area when the mouse cursor is moved over the HTML document.
>
> **Expected Output**
>
> ### [image]

## Solution

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <meta charset="UTF-8">
        <title>Track mouse coordinates</title>
    </head>
    <body>
        <div style="background-color:#8F9779;height:30px;">
        </div>
        <script type="text/javascript">
            var mie = (navigator.appName == "Microsoft Internet Explorer") ? true : false;
            if(!mie){
                document.captureEvents(Event.MOUSEMOVE);
            }
            document.onmousemove = mousePos;

            var mouseX = 0;
            var mouseY = 0;

            function mousePos(e){
                if(!mie){
                    mouseX = e.pageX;
                    mouseY = e.pageY;
                }
                else{
                    mouseX = e.clientX + document.body.scrollLeft;
                    mouseY = e.clientY + document.body.scrollRight;
                }

                /*document.write clears the document and all the event handlers inside it*/
                document.body.innerHTML += "X: " + mouseX + ";Y: " + mouseY + ";  Time: " + new Date() + "<br>";    
                return true;
            }
        </script>
    </body>
</html>
```

---

Above code is written using deprecated API `captureEvents`.[MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window/captureEvents) says, `captureEvents` is deprecated.

Code still works fine with this deprecated API.

Can this code be improved, by replacing `captureEvents` with a better standard API?

Answer (score 5):

`mie` isn't a good variable name. `usesIE` would be better, or well.. something like that!

Why is `mouseX` and `mouseY` defined outside your method's scope? They're useless there.

I don't think keeping variable at the root of the script is a good practice. Why don't you wrap it inside a `window.onload` call?

The only comment in your code seems useless. You do not use `document.write` anywhere in your code.

Also, when you have the choice, your conditions should be positive. It's just a little easier to read.

I don't see the use of returning `true` in a case like that. It means nothing.

Finally, I think that it'd be better to pass the `usesIE` parameter to the `mousePos` function. By the way, `mousePos` should be renamed `writeMousePosition`.

This is what the final code would look like :

```
function writeMousePosition(args,usesIE) {
    var mouseX = 0; 
    var mouseY = 0;

    if(usesIE) {
        mouseX = args.clientX + document.body.scrollLeft;
        mouseY = args.clientY + document.body.scrollRight;
    } else {
        mouseX = args.pageX;
        mouseY = args.pageY;
    }

    document.body.innerHTML += "X: " + mouseX + ";Y: " + mouseY + ";  Time: " + new Date() + "<br>";
}

window.onload = function() {
    var usesIE = (navigator.appName == "Microsoft Internet Explorer") ? true : false;

    if(!usesIE) {
        document.captureEvents(Event.MOUSEMOVE);
    }

    document.onmousemove = function(args) {
        writeMousePosition(args, usesIE);
    };
};
```

Comment: Can you please answer on deprecated api, as mentioned in query?

Comment: @overexchange I'd like to but I'm not really aware of the API, sorry.

Answer (score 2):

#### Repeating redundancy

> ```
> var mie = (navigator.appName == "Microsoft Internet Explorer") ? true : false;
> ```

You must be from the Department of Redundancy DPT. The above expression is equivalent to:

```
 var mie = navigator.appName == "Microsoft Internet Explorer";
```

---

#### Add me!

> ```
> document.onmousemove = function(args) {
> ```

It is bad practice to just set the `event` property in JavaScript. Why? Because you override every other listener that fires on that event.

Instead, you should use `addEventListener`.

```
document.addEventListener("mousemove", function(args) {
    ...
});
```

---

> ```
> document.body.innerHTML += "X: " + mouseX + ";Y: " + mouseY + ";  Time: " + new Date() + "<br>";
> ```

Yeah, I get that the point of this code is to write the coordinates. However, this is bad practice because you are both computing something *and* giving output in the same function.

You should have this function return the `x` and `y` coordinates instead of that completely necessary `true`, and have the caller write the output.

Answer (score 0):

If you can use jquery it is just:

```
$( "#container" ).mousemove(function( event )
```

and use the event argumet.

## Demo

```js
$( "#container" ).mousemove(function( event ) {
  $( "#container" ).prepend( "X: " + event.pageX + ";Y: " + event.pageY + ";  Time: " + new Date() + "<br>");                
});
```

```css
#container{
  height:180px;
  width:620px;
  background-color:lightgrey;
  overflow: auto;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.0.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="container"></div>
```